# DELETE by date, is there a wildcard?

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all entries from specific dates, but in my date field I also have the time.

Is there something like a wildcard that I could use ? like:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE time='01.01.2010 WILDCARD';
```

the time would be where i wrote WILDCARD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DATE()` function.

`DELETE FROM table WHERE DATE(time) = '2010-01-01'`

Comment: Alas, this is not able to use an index over `time`.

Answer (score 1):

To effecively use any index on `DateTimeColumn`:

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE DateTimeColumn >= '2010-01-01'
  AND DateTimeColumn <  '2010-01-02' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `BETWEEN`:

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE DateTimeColumn BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2010-01-01 23:59:59';
```

resp. `23:59:61`, as I don't know if MySQL handles leap seconds approriately.

Alternatively, I would suggest to modify [ybercube's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10911043/296974) and do

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE DateTimeColumn >= '2010-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND DateTimeColumn <  '2010-01-02 00:00:00';
```

Note that I am not sure if this 2nd solution is completely equivalent to ybercube's one, or if there are any differences in certain cases such as conversion problems or latencies between date and datetime format.